# How to add a page in ionic project with blank template and load its template into index.html by setting states and controller?

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation

I want to set base url to load template from /templates and associated /controller. The problem is that it is not getting loaded on base url, base url has index.html as it is and then base url+"/#/" loads my second page which i want to be loaded with index.html at the app launch. I believe i am going wrong with setting state. I want to configure a single state for now, a single page whose template gets mapped into index.html. Any solution?

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'CalendarCtrl' ,'onezone-datepicker'])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
       $stateProvider
       .state('/', 
        { url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'templates/calendar.html',
          controller: 'CalendarCtrl'
        });
    })
```

Comment: please explain little more!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "templates/page.html"
})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Edison I don't see this implementation on ionic documentation. I have done it mean stack though like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm assuming wrong, but from your question it seems you are new to Ionic.  Since there's not much explanation to your question, I'll clarify what you are looking at in your code.

Basically what you want to do is make a file called "page.html" in your templates folder and control it with the 'PageCtrl' you have declared here.

If you want to simply use Index.html for all your html, then I guess you can do that too.  Make sure in your index.html you have:

```
<html ng-app="starter"> ....
<script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
</html>
<head>..... </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
</body>
</html>
```

Replace "MainCtrl" with whatever controller you decide to control your index page with.

Hope that helps. Don't give up!

Comment: You are right @parynaz, indeed. I have used angular in mean. I want to get something which ng-route does. We don't set controller for index file, templates get mapped into it via ng-view directive and each of those template has a assigned controller. Simply put, I want to load my templates in index.html just as we do in mean.